# Magento installing issue _ Installer.php line 546: Missing following extensions: 'sodium'

Tags: magento2

I need help on resolving this magento installing issue- Installer.php line 546:    Missing following extensions: 'sodium'

if someone would love to resolve this issue really appreciated.

reference pic attached

Thanks and Regards
Magento user

Answer (score 1):

Install sodium using below commands

wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz

tar -xzvf libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz

cd libsodium-1.0.18

./configure

make && make check

sudo make install

sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install -f libsodium

sudo echo "extension=sodium" >> /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

php -m | grep sodium

Answer (score 0):

Sodium Extension Missing

Try the Solutions :

**I -** Install Manually Sodium PHP extension by adding bellow

> extension =sodium

in your php ini file.
***your-php-ini-path***
In my case I am using xampp so its : /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Note : After adding restart lampp/apache server whichever you are using

OR

**II -** Install using CMD

> sudo pecl install -f libsodium

Comment: libsodium is already within the folder but still Cmd throwing error its missing in your system

Comment: Have you checked which php is been used means are you using more than one php..?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what distributive and repo you are using. In CentOS, you could do `yum install php-sodium`. Usually, no need to add any configuration files, because it would add the PHP module config automatically during installation.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html